# How to access sqlite DB on the Xoom?

Tags: android, sqlite, root, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a Nexus One (rooted) and a Xoom (stock, not rooted).
I have developed on my Nexus for quite some time, without any problems. I'm facing one with the Xoom, however, as it is not rooted.

Indeed, I use sqlite databases in my apps, and I would like to debug them using sqlite3 as I do on my Nexus.

It doesn't work!

```
$ pwd
/
$ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1009(mount),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),3001(net_b_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet)
$ sqlite3 /data/data/org.bicou.newsreader/databases/subscriptions.db
sqlite3: permission denied
```

I can't! How come? How am I supposed to develop? I'm sure I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Also, adb pull doesn't want to pull, and cat / cp / mv don't work either. I don't want to write specific code in my app just to browse the DB...

Comment: I ended up rooting the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rooting the device.

(answser input only for marking it as accepted)

Answer (score 1):

If it is **your** app you're debugging, there is no need to root the device.

Edit this list of commands to your package name and db file name, and paste it into a shell:

```
adb wait-for-device shell <<EOF
run-as [YOUR_PNAME] 
chmod 666 databases/[YOUR_DB_FILE_NAME].db
exit
exit
EOF

adb pull /data/data/[YOUR_PNAME]/databases/[YOUR_DB_FILE_NAME].db
sqlitebrowser [YOUR_DB_FILE_NAME].db &
```

The `sqlitebrowser` can be replaced with whatever sqlite3 application you have on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

I rooted my device as well. But new system image doesn't have sqlite3 in path.

Comment: I used adb pull to get the files, and then I browse with an app on the laptop.