# Can I use sqlite 3 on non rooted device

Tags: android, sqlite, root-access

Hi all, I am aware how to use sqlite3 on emulator to monitor data of app. Is it possible to use on a real device?
My device is Nexus S when I try on my device it says sqlite3 is not found. Is it compulsory to sqlite 3 device must be a rooted one? My device is not a rooted device.

I am aware of other mechanism of looking data for example dump db file in SD card then use third party SQL browser to look into the data.

Comment: Please, clarify what you are asking. Of course, you can use SQLite dbs on non rooted devices. You wouldn't be even able to read and save your contacts, otherwise (since a SQLite db is used for contacts).

Comment: Yes you can use sqlite without root permission.As i understand your question there is no sqlite file in assets folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about using sqlite3 on shell (terminal), then no -- first you can't access the databases folder in your app because of permissions. second there's probably no sqlite3 installed in your non-rooted phone.

lucky enough, your nexus s, being a nexus device, is one of the easiest devices to root. there's even a tool created to root any nexus device - get it [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEsQFjAC&url=http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/&ei=9dVHU7XGHqnQiAeXt4DwBw&usg=AFQjCNEhmK95QEdAbBSg1wGdlI-jGCHWlQ&sig2=K-BgWEjW91hNasKTVgNzJA&bvm=bv.64542518,d.aGc).

After rooting, follow instructions on the third post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-op) to install sqlite.

Comment: Actually no need to root, if the app is debuggable. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23387205/1180898 - but the second part is correct (no sqlite on device) - but you can edit/query/whatever on a pc and push it back

Answer (score 2):

U cant use Sqlite3 instead u can do this.
The following solution works only for apps that are debuggable. It may not work well on all devices, since ​​run-as command doesn't work on some devices, especially with Jelly Bean.

1. ​Create a *.bat or a *.sh file and copy the following scripts ​​

   **adb shell run-as [package] chmod 777 /data/data/[package]/databases/**

   **adb shell run-as [package] chmod 777  data/data/[package]/databases/[db_file_name]**

   **adb shell cp /data/data/[package]/databases/[db_file_name] /sdcard/**

   **adb pull /sdcard/[db_file_name]**
2. ​Change [package] to the desired application package
3. Change [db_file_name] to the desired db name Run the bat file and
   you should see the copied database in the same folder as the bat
   file